# What is $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\int_{a}^{b}f(x,\sin(tx))dx$？

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, analysis

Let f $\in C([a,b]\times [-1,1]) $,What is the value of this integral:

$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\int_{a}^{b}f(x,sin(tx))dx$

This is a topic I encountered when I was studying mathematical analysis recently, I want to know how to solve this problem, is there some theoretical background?
First of all, f is a bounded continuous binary function, so we can get that this integral must also be bounded.Then I tried the commutation method so that tx=u, but I couldn't push the final result.
This is the result of my appeal operation：
$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{t}\int_{at}^{bt}f(\frac{u}{t},sin(u))du$ 
I would appreciate it if you could solve it.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: "what is the background of this question" as mentioned in the comment above, you are the one who should be providing the context

Comment: There is no general solution. It all depends on the specific form of $f$ and its dependence of $sin(xt)$.

Comment: @M.Wind,I think the final form of this topic is expressed in f, a, b。such as f(x,y)=x+y,the rusult is (b^2-a^2)/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that
$$
\lim_{t \to \infty}\int_a^b f(x,\sin(tx)) dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_a^b \int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\sin(s)) ds dx.
$$

First, let $g \in C^1([a,b])$ and note that for $n \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus \{0\}$
$$
\int_a^b g(x)\exp(itnx) dx \to 0 \quad (t \to \infty),
$$
which can be proved by partial integration.
Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and consider
$$
\int_a^b g(x) (\sin(tx))^n dx = \int_a^b g(x) \frac{1}{(2i)^n}(\exp(itx) - \exp(-itx))^n dx
$$
$$
=\int_a^bg(x) \frac{1}{(2i)^n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k} (-1)^k\exp(it(n-2k)x) dx
$$
$$
\to\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
0, & 2 \nmid n \\
\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{(2i)^n}{n\choose n/2}\int_a^bg(x)  dx,& 2 \mid n
\end{array} \right. \quad (t \to \infty).
$$
With a similar reasoning we get
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} (\sin(x))^n dx =  \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1}{(2i)^n} \sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}(-1)^k \exp(i(n-2k)x) dx
$$
$$
=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
0, & 2 \nmid n \\
\frac{(-1)^{n/2}}{(2i)^n}{n\choose n/2}, & 2 \mid n
\end{array} \right.
$$
Thus
$$
(\ast) \quad \int_a^b g(x) (\sin(tx))^n dx \to \int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} g(x)(\sin(s))^n ds dx \quad (t \to \infty).
$$
Now let $f \in C([a,b] \times [-1,1])$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. By the Weierstrass Approximation Theorem there is some polynomial $p(x,y)$ such that
$$
|f(x,y)-p(x,y)| \le \varepsilon \quad ((x,y) \in [a,b] \times [-1,1]).
$$
Application of $(\ast)$ to the monomials $x^m(\sin(tx))^n$ leads to
$$
\int_a^b p(x,\sin(tx)) dx \to \int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(x,\sin(s)) ds dx \quad (t \to \infty).
$$
Thus, there is some $t_0 > 0$ such that for $t \ge t_0$:
$$
|\int_a^b p(x,\sin(tx)) dx -\int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(x,\sin(s)) ds dx| < \varepsilon,
$$
hence
$$
|\int_a^b f(x,\sin(tx)) dx - \int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\sin(s)) ds dx | 
$$
$$
\le |\int_a^b f(x,\sin(tx)) dx - \int_a^b p(x,\sin(tx)) dx| 
$$
$$
+ |\int_a^b p(x,\sin(tx)) dx -\int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(x,\sin(s)) ds dx |
$$
$$
+|\int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} p(x,\sin(s)) ds dx - \int_a^b \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x,\sin(s)) ds dx |
$$
$$
\le (b-a) \varepsilon + \varepsilon + (b-a) \varepsilon = (2(b-a)+1)\varepsilon.
$$