# (Dis)Proving $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{x^s}\int_0^xt^{s-1}f(\sin t)dt=\frac1{2\pi s}\int_0^{2\pi}f(\sin t)dt$, for $s>0$ and $f$ defined on $[-1,1]$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

> Prove (or disprove) the following conjecture:
>
> Given $s>0$, function $f(x)$ is defined for all $x\in[-1;1]$, then:
> $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x^s}\int_0^x t^{s-1}f(\sin(t))\,dt=\frac{1}{2{\pi}s}\int_0^{2\pi} f(\sin(t))\,dt$$

I can only prove the conjecture for $s=2$ (using $\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi}tf(\sin(t))\,dt=\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}\int_0^{(2n+1)\pi}f(\sin(t))\,dt$ ($*$)) and $s=1$ (obvious). However, the substitution trick $t=(2n+1)\pi-u$ in ($*$) doesn't work for $s$ is even or $s$ is non-integer. It seems to me that the conjecture is true but all my tools for evaluating limit problems don't work here.
(**Update**) **The answer to the problem above was done in** [What is $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty }\int_{a}^{b}f(x,\sin(tx))dx$？](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566609/what-is-lim-t-rightarrow-infty-int-abfx-sintxdx/4569585#4569585)
(I moved my generalization to another post)

Comment: With no loss of generality you may assume that $f\ge 0.$ It suffices to consider $x=2n\pi$ with $n\to \infty.$ Then you can split the integral over $[2(k-1)\pi,2k\pi]$. Each integral can be estimated below and above by the appropriate values of $t^{s-1}$ times the integral of $f(\sin t).$ It should work I hope.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566609/what-is-lim-t-rightarrow-infty-int-abfx-sintxdx/4569585#4569585

Comment: @Gerd Amazing proof! How unfortunate that the original post was closed. By the way, I wonder whether we can generalize the formula for general curves and n-dimensional analogy

Comment: Thanks. The proof relies on properties of sinus. For a generalization to periodic functions I think a different method is needful.